# Powershell - Skip adding users to distro group that are already in it

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add users to a distribution group, but ignore any users that are already in it.

I've got the below so far but its not working, i believe possibly as the $user variable only contains an email rather than a user object

```
$users = Get-Content "H:\Documents\Powershell\users.txt"
$groupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter full group name'
$dl=Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupName

$(foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($dl -notcontains $user) {
        Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Member $user
        Add-Content $success "`nAdded user '$($user) to '$($groupName)"
    }   
})
```

Comment: You're comparing an object `$dl` with a string `$user`, `-notcontains` would work if you were checking for an `array` not containing a `string`. In summary, you need to tell what property of your `$dl` object you want to compare with `$user`. If `$user` were the email of the user you could use `$dl.PrimarySMTPAddress`; if `$user` were userNames you could use `$dl.Name`

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your code to something like this:

```
$users = Get-Content "H:\Documents\Powershell\users.txt"
$groupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Enter full group name'
$dl=Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupName | Select PrimarySmtpAddress

$(foreach ($user in $users) {
    if (-not ($dl -contains $user)) {
        Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Member $user
        Add-Content $success "`nAdded user '$($user) to '$($groupName)"
    }   
})
```

Comment: Its still trying to add users that are already in the group